# Vue JS send data from v-for on button click

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm new to Vue JS, and i'm having a little problem

i'm looping through an array and i have a button inside the div that i'm looping with

the idea is to get the data of the specified data after the click event

for example let's say i have this array `numbers: [1,2,3,4,5]` and i'm looping through it like this

```
<div v-for="number in numbers">
    <p>{{ number }}</p>
    <button v-on:click="getTheSelectedOne"> Get The Value </button>
</div>
```

i tried doing so

```
<button v-on:click="getTheValueOfTheSelectedOne(number)"> Get The Value </button>
```

but i got an error,

how can i achieve such a result ?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 10):

```
<div v-for="number in numbers">
```

Should be:

```
<div v-for="(number, index) in numbers" :key="index">
```

The following:

```
<button v-on:click="getTheSelectedOne"> Get The Value </button>
```

Should be:

```
<button v-on:click="getTheSelectedOne(number)"> Get The Value </button>
```

And you must have that method defined:

```
methods: {
  getTheSelectedOne (number) {
    // then number will be the number
    console.log(number)
  }
}
```

Comment: v-for can be used both ways, so i guess that shouldn't be the problem: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

Comment: most linters will complain, In 2.2.0+, when using v-for with a component, a key is now required. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Comment: Though the error is most likely getTheSelectedOne not being defined, but who knows till the OP makes contact.

Comment: Ah. Missed the part about the key! Yeah. for that use case it is needed.